# Error while trying to automate mutt using C

Tags: linux, c, mutt

I am trying to automate mutt in C. To send a mail with attachment in mutt one can use: `echo "what_you_want_to_print_in_body" | mutt -s "Subject" -a "file_path" -- recipient@domain.com` but when I automate the same using this C program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char echo_message[1000];
char path[1000];
char subject[1000];
char recepient[1000];

printf("Enter your mail message: ");
gets(echo_message);
printf("Enter the path: ");
gets(path);
printf("Enter the subject: ");
gets(subject);
printf("Enter the recipient address: ");
gets(recepient);

system("echo \"%s\" | mutt -s \"%s\" -a \"%s\" -- \"%s\"", &echo_message, &subject, &path, &recepient);

return 0;
}
```

I get an error saying:

```
Can't stat %s: No such file or directory
%s: unable to attach a file.
```

I asked this question here as my concern was whether my system() script is valid, if not how should I proceed to automate this task.

Comment: The `system()` library function only takes a single argument, a string.

Comment: So in order to automate this task, do I have to use a shell script

Comment: SECURITY CONSIDERATIONS - The gets() function cannot be used securely.  Because of its lack of ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lack the `<stdlib.h>` header, and including it you would notice that the compiler tells you that the `system()` library function only takes a single argument, a string.

You make no attempt at cleaning up the user-supplied data. Entering `robert@example.com"; rm -rf /; : "` (or something similar) as the recipient would not end well. Don't do this.

Input validation and preventing exploits through `system()` when using user-supplied data is *hard*.

Related: https://xkcd.com/327/